# How to post a file to a protected URL using apache httpclient 4.3.5

Tags: java, apache-httpclient-4.x

I need to post a file to a protected url with a set of request parameters using apache httpclient 4.3.5. Could you please share some sample code for the same?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

If your question is about uploading a file using apache httpclient you can do that as a multi-part request [check this out](http://www.accordess.com/wpblog/file-upload-apache-httpclient-library/)